# Converting Varchar to INT while using LEN() Function

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to cast a varchar field to an int

```
 Cast(Len((VarcharFLD)-1)as Int)
```

Essentially if the value for the field was A555 My result would be 3 as I am only looking for the Length of the field.  I get an error that says Conversion Failed When Converting the varchar value 'A555' to data type int.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: wouldn't be the return of len be an int? why would you want to cast it again to int?

Answer (score 3):

This is the expression you want:

```
Len(VarcharFLD)-1
```

The result of `len()` *is* an integer.  You don't need to convert it again.

However, your error is being caused by bad parentheses.  Your expression is:

```
Cast(Len( (VarcharFLD)-1)as Int)
----------------------^
```

The minus is being applied to`VarcharFLD` rather than to the result of `len()`.  Because the field does not contain a numeric value, this generates an error.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

( Len(VarcharFLD)-1 )

Answer (score 0):

You have wrongly put the brackets.

select Cast((Len(VarcharFLD)-1)as Int)

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for the Length of the field, use:

```
select Len(isnull(VarcharFLD, ''))
```

I do not understand why you use -1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Function which extracts Numbers from a given string ..

**Function Definition**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_GetNumbers
(@strAlphaNumeric VARCHAR(4000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @intAlpha INT

  SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric)

BEGIN
  WHILE @intAlpha > 0
    BEGIN
      SET @strAlphaNumeric = STUFF(@strAlphaNumeric, @intAlpha, 1, '' )
      SET @intAlpha = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @strAlphaNumeric )
    END
END

    RETURN ISNULL(@strAlphaNumeric,0)
END
GO
```

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(StringColumn VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('ABC1'),('ABC12'),('ABC123'),('ABC1234')
```

**Query**

Use the Function as follows in your query.

```
SELECT LEN(dbo.udf_GetNumbers(StringColumn)) AS Lenght
FROM @TABLE
```

**Result Set**

```
╔════════╗
║ Lenght ║
╠════════╣
║      1 ║
║      2 ║
║      3 ║
║      4 ║
╚════════╝
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1c78/1)